# Node.js Basic Questions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking into learning about node.js. I've just installed it on Windows. I've done some research but everyone seems to be jumping right into code, that can come later and there are plenty of resources for me to look that stuff up. What I need to know is much more basic.

1. Is Node.js is bascially a small webserver, similar to a local-hosted Apache? Yes or no?
2. Tutorials always start with a simple program. Where does the Node.js server look for these files? Where do I save my .js files so that node.js can see them? Can I have sub-directories?
3. How do I change where node.js looks for .js files?
4. Is node.js always running or can it be turned on and off like Apache?
5. What is one simple example (high level, no code needed) of how a website would talk to node.js?

Comment: This is all pretty straightforward stuff that is answered on the [node.js homepage](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: [Short book with answers for all your questions](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)

Comment: To those downvoting this question... these questions come up often.  There are a ton of misconceptions about what Node.js is.  I think this question should stay.  The questions are specific and very clear.  There is no reason to close this question.

Comment: I agree with Brad, and was about to post my own answer before his much better answer popped up.

Comment: If these questions come up often isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: @Brad No, a list of various no-code trivial questions doesn't make a good SO question. And when it ends with a request for a sample...

Comment: @Andy If you can find the duplicates, feel free to close as a duplicate.  Usually though these questions come up and are poorly asked, and are deleted within minutes.  These are clear, well-worded questions and I think they should stay.

Comment: @dystroy I couldn't disagree more.  They are directly related to coding with Node.js, and I don't think they are trivial at all.  They hit at the core of what you need to know to develop with Node.js.

Comment: [Don't ask more than one question in one question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77199/asking-many-questions-in-one)

Comment: @dystroy I can agree with you on that point.  While I do think that all 5 questions are getting around the same thing, "What is Node.js", I don't disagree that they could have been broken up.

Comment: I needed these high level questions answered to get me off the ground and now that I have the high-level information that I need, you can close it if that would make you a happy camper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `1. Is Node.js is bascially a small webserver, similar to a local-hosted Apache? Yes or no?

No.  Node.js is an application platform.  It's often used for web applications, and it does have built-in HTTP servers and clients, but it can be used for much more beyond that.

> `2. Tutorials always start with a simple program. Where does the Node.js server look for these files? Where do I save my .js files so that node.js can see them? Can I have sub-directories?

Wherever you want.  Node.js doesn't look for them in any place in particular.  You start your application with `node path/to/your/file.js`.

> `3. How do I change where node.js looks for .js files?

You don't.  Node doesn't have any global config that tells it where to look for files.

> `4. Is node.js always running or can it be turned on and off like Apache?

You can run it as a service or daemon like Apache, or just start it as-needed like Apache.

> `5. What is one simple example (high level, no code needed) of how a website would talk to node.js?

That depends **entirely** on the application.  Many just use HTTP, some use WebSockets.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you think this answer is incorrect, you best add a comment to explain why, for everyone's benefit.

Comment: This answer works for me, it answered all my questions and removed some of the fog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Short answer: no.  Node is really just a *JavaScript container*: that is, it is designed to run JavaScript, just like your browser (it just doesn't have the DOM, or any of the other trappings of the browser).  It just so happens that it also has libraries that allow you to very easily *write* a webserver.  That is, Node itself is NOT a webserver, but you can quite easily call `http.createServer` or `https.createServer`, and then your app *becomes* a webserver.
2. You can put your .js files anywhere, and Node will read them.  If you have `foo.js` in any directory, all you have to do is type `node foo.js` to run it.  It's very command-line centric, though I'm sure there are some GUI clients out there if that's your thing (I actually understand Visual Studio integration is quite good at this point, for example).
3. See #2.
4. Node only runs when you tell it to (`node foo.js`).  There are ways to daemonize it so that it runs automatically, and/or restarts automatically, but by itself, it doesn't do anything until you tell it to.
5. In addition to all the functions available to JavaScript, Node makes many libraries available to your app.  The primary ones are `http` and `https`.  They are all documented here: http://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: Apparently on windows (not sure about *nix) Node won't read them unless you give it a path on the command line like this: node C:\Path\To\My\file.js

Comment: @S.Mason That isn't true.  I use `node file.js` all the time on Windows.

Comment: OK I see you can navigate to the path where the file resides in the command prompt, then call 'node' and you won't need the full path to the .js file. That's the kind of stuff that everyone just expects beginners to just innately know, but that's why we're beginners! We don't know.)